# Unexpected token '}' in JSON at object.parse at node-haste/lib/packager.js

Tags: android, windows, reactjs, react-native

I am using React Native 0.31 for Android at Windows 7 pro machine. Getting the below error when launching the app. Have anyone face this kind of issue? Any advice would be highly appreciated. Please note that this app has been worked before without any (of these) issues.

> [node-haste] Encountered an error while persisting cache:
>
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token } in JSON at position 892
>       at Object.parse (native)
>       at e:\Projects\27-04-2016\sample-app\node_modules\node-haste\lib\Package.js:112:23

Comment: add JSON data too

Comment: This is usually when your JSON data is not in the correct format. Did you change the data? Like @Ganesh asked please provide as with the JSON data that you are receiving.

Comment: Updated the question with JSON @LianvanderVyver

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON data need to be inside `[]` tags.

Currently your data looks like:

```
{"MallShopID1":6027,"ShopID":10},
{"MallShopID1":6028,"ShopID":11}
```

But needs to look like:

```
[{"MallShopID1":6027,"ShopID":10},
{"MallShopID1":6028,"ShopID":11}]
```

You can look at a [JSON validator](http://jsonlint.com) next time to see if there is something wrong with your data.

Comment: Yes, you are it a json array. I had removed square brackets. JSONlint.com results valid json.

Comment: @MuruganDurai sorry not sure what you are saying. Were you able to fix your problem?

Comment: Issue is not yet fixed but that JSON array has been verfied & result is positive at jsonlint.com

Comment: Mmmm, Can you show us the code on how you fetch your data in react-native

Answer (score 0):

Lets say your json data is like this

```
[
    {"MallShopID1":6027,"ShopID":10},
    {"MallShopID1":6028,"ShopID":11},
    {"MallShopID1":6029,"ShopID":12},
    {"MallShopID1":6030,"ShopID":13},
]
```

in this case comma after `"shopID":13` 
That comma in the end will cause this warning. Same goes for nested JSON,

```
 [
    {"MallShopID1":6027,
     "ShopID":10, 
     "shopdetails": {
        "name" : "shopName",
        "city": "shopCity",
      }},
    {"MallShopID1":6028,"ShopID":11},
    {"MallShopID1":6029,"ShopID":12},
    {"MallShopID1":6030,"ShopID":13},
 ]
```

Here comma after `{"MallShopID1":6030,"ShopID":13},` and `"city": "shopCity",`.

Trailing commas are allowed in JavaScript, Douglas Crockford's versionless JSON spec didn't allow them, and because it was versionless this wasn't supposed to change. The ES5 JSON spec allowed them as an extension, but Crockford's RFC 4627 didn't, and ES5 reverted to disallowing them.